# Trying to supress resource warning in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, resources, warnings, suppress-warnings

I want to suppress the "The resource name 'X.Y' is not a valid identifier" warnings in Visual Studio 2008.

I cannot find the warning number to supress it in the project's properties. Is there another way of achieving this, or better still, does anyone know the warning number?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228672(VS.80).aspx), your deployment tool will generate a substitute for the file name of this resource.

To correct this error

> You should first change the name of
>   the resource to a valid identifier, if
>   possible. If that is not a valid
>   option, **disable strongly typed
>   resource code generation** for this
>   .resx file. To do this, select the
>   .resx file in **Solution Explorer** and
>   clear the **Custom Tool** property.

Comment: Then you need to make sure you use valid filenames.